# Com Exception While Accessing MailItem from Outlook using c#

Tags: c#, .net, outlook

Hi I am working on C# application in which i am trying to read the mails from the Outlook Inbox.
I am using VS2010 and MS-Office 2007, I have added the refernce in the visual studio, The application is working fine in my system, but when i run the same application in client system, its throwing COM exception,

The exception message is like this

**Unable to cast COM object of type System_ComObject to InterfaceType "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem" . This operation failed because the QueryInterface Call on the Com Component for the Interface with ID'{00063034-0000-0000-C000-00000000046} failed due to the following error.  No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002)
(E_NONINTERFACE)**

I am getting exception while trying to access **MailItem** ex code :
 **subject = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)myInbox.Items[i]).Subject;**
I tested in 3 to 4 systems in which VS2010 is installed, and the client system in which its throwing exception doesnt contain vs2010 in it, but .net 4.0 framework,ms-office 2007 is installed in client system.

what may be the error ?
Any suggestions plz ..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: How is the myInbox defined ? Maybe the user has something else in the myInbox than MailItem (invite for example?).

Comment: Is the client system maybe .Net 4 Client Profile? Where the machines containing Visual Studio have the full .Net 4 framework?

Comment: Post the relevant code by the way

Comment: myApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace mapiNameSpace = myApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder myInbox=mapiNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
 mapiNameSpace.SendAndReceive(false);
if (myInbox.Items.Count > 0)
 {
    subject = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)myInbox.Items[i]).Subject;
                            subject = subject.Replace('\'', '\"');
                 }

Answer (score 0):

Well there are two errors here - not all items in Inbox are of type MailItem, secondly subject can be null; so the correct code should look like:

```
  using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

  var myApp = new Application();
  NameSpace mapiNameSpace = myApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
  MAPIFolder myInbox = mapiNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
  mapiNameSpace.SendAndReceive(false);
  if (myInbox.Items.Count > 0) {
    for (var i = 1; i < myInbox.Items.Count; i++) {
      string subject;
      var mailItem = myInbox.Items[i] as MailItem;
      if (mailItem != null) {
        subject = mailItem.Subject;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(subject)) {
          subject = subject.Replace('\'', '\"');
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

where the most important line is

```
  var mailItem = myInbox.Items[i] as MailItem;
  if (mailItem != null) {
     ...
```

and

```
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(subject)) {
     ...
```